# Recuperar informações de um sharedPreference Android

Tags: android

Boa noite, tenho algumas informações salvas em SharedPreferences(email e senha) e preciso recuperar as mesmas em diversos locais para uso.
Criei um fragment para o usuário poder salvar a tela:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_user_email"
    android:title="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_user_password"
    android:title="Senha"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

Isso está funcionando perfeitamente, porém como posso fazer para por exemplo recuperar a informação do email(pref_user_email)?
Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você quer usar em vários lugares, pode criar um método estático que retorne a string que quer.
  Crie uma classe e crie esse método estático dentro dela.

```
 public class Preferencias_Usuario
{
    public static String getEmail(Context pContext)
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = pContext.getSharedPreferences(pContext.getString(R.string.pref_user_email), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String result = settings.getString(pContext.getString(R.string.pref_user_email), "");
        if (result.length() > 0)
            return result;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Assim retorna o email, pode fazer pra retornar os outros dados também.

Pra usar: `Preferencias_Usuario.getEmail(Main_Activity.this)`

No `Main_Activity.this` pass a activity que está usando.

Answer (score 0):

tenta isso ó:

```
// ...
private SharedPreferences prefs;
//...
private void emUmMetodoQualquer(){
    //...
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    ppf = prefs.getString("ppftexto", "texto");
    // ppftexto eh a referencia, texto eh um valor default
    showTooltip = prefs.getBoolean("showtooltips", false);
    // no caso pega um valor booleano
    if (prefs.getString("ppftexto", "texto").equals("TextoquequeroA")) {
        // faz algo aqui
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude